# Issues with json strings and django templates

Tags: javascript, django, json

I am trying to query a list of data, convert it into a json object, and pass it into my javascript so it can be evaluated there:

```
var data = '{{ passed_list|jsonify }}';

# This evaluates to:

var news = '[{&quot;pk&quot;: 133, &quot;model&quot;: &quot;Article.article
    &quot;,&quot;fields&quot;:
```

However, this wont work because I am trying to access elements.

For example,

```
var object = data[0].pk;
In my view source, this does not evaluate to 133 as expected but it evaluates
to ... data[0].pk ... which is a bit confusing.
```

Here is my jsonify:

```
 if isinstance(object, QuerySet):
    return serialize('json', object)
return simplejson.dumps(object, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django will escape html characters by default

**if you completely trust the data**, (i.e. it comes from your code, and no part of the content could come from a user), you can use

```
var data = '{{ passed_list|jsonify|safe }}';
```

to tell django not to escape it

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that it's almost solved, there is just one more small issue, chrome's debugger is saying there is an "unexpected identifier with the comma betweeen china and s. "title": "China's Toxic Milk Whistleblower Murdered", how should this be handled if I want to escape that quote, but not others?

Comment: sounds like a bug in your `jsonify`.. does it return valid json?

Comment: Yes, I actually used django's default snippet for jsonify i updated it in my main post.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, I was just being really stupid. '{{ passed_list|jsonify }}' makes no sense, why would I even include those quotes, for some reason, on many online json guides, many people have single quotes on their json objects, not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = '{{ portfolio|jsonify|escapejs|safe }}';
```

Filter *escapejs* put after *jsonify* solves the problem with special characters like: *'*